# Size limit on BufferedReader exceeded?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

In a java 6 webapp, I am attempting to retrieve a large amount of output from an executed command.  I've "borrowed/stolen/based" it on the [javaworld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=3).  The problem I am facing is that the length appears to exceed a size limit since the output is lopped off.  I've output the data to a file so I can see the size of what is returned, and that is exactly 32K (32768).  I've experimented with changing the default size of the buffer (see BufferedReader constructor), but I have not observed any change to the length of the data returned no matter what value I have for the buffered-size (very small to very large).

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

```
public class StreamGobbler extends Thread {

private InputStream is;
private String type;
private List<String> output;

public StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type) {
    this.is = is;
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        this.output = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            this.getOutput().add(line + "\n");
            System.out.println(type + ">" + line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * @return the output
 */
public List<String> getOutput() {
    return output;
}
```

}

```
public class JobClassAds {

private String CONDOR_HISTORY = "condor_history";
private String CONDOR_HISTORY_XML = CONDOR_HISTORY + " -xml";
private String CONDOR_HISTORY_LONG = CONDOR_HISTORY + " -long";

public String getHistory() {
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String exec = CONDOR_HISTORY_LONG;
        Process process = runtime.exec(exec);
        System.out.println("Running " + exec + " ...");

        // Error message
        StreamGobbler errGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");

        // Output
        StreamGobbler outGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

        Thread outThread = new Thread(outGobbler);
        Thread errThread = new Thread(errGobbler);

        outThread.start();
        errThread.start();

        outThread.join();
        errThread.join();

        /*
        String line = null;

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            content.append(line);
        }

         *
         */

        int exitVal = process.waitFor();

        List<String> output = outGobbler.getOutput();
        String inputString = "";
        for (String o : output) {
            inputString += o;
        }

        System.out.println(exec + " Exited with error code " + exitVal);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/history_result.xml"));
        out.write(inputString);
        out.close();
        return inputString;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the buffer size on BufferedReader will just change the amount of temporary storage it uses internally. BufferedReader doesn't have a size limit, so you should be able to read the entire output with this code. Have you checked that condor_history -long itself produces the full output and doesn't stop at 32k?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  Running the command returns complete output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the `BufferedReader`'s buffer size.

I think that the real cause is something that the external command is doing.  I suspect that it is bailing out without flushing its stdout stream.  Note that you are "gobbling" but not outputting the command's stderr stream.  That's where you may find the evidence pointing to the real cause of the problem.

---

By the way, you are using the `StreamGobbler` class in a suboptimal fashion.  It extends `Thread` so the intended way to use is:

```
    SteamGobbler sg = new StreamGobbler(...);
    sg.start();
    sg.join();
```

but you are effectively doing this:

```
    SteamGobbler sg = new StreamGobbler(...);
    Thread th = new Thread(sg);
    th.start();
    th.join();
```

It works ... but only because a `Thread` *is-a* `Runnable`.

Comment: Thank you.  Running cli returns the complete output.  Appreciate the feedback on the Thread.  That is how I had it originally, so I have reverted it.

Comment: @samiam - *"Running cli returns the complete output."*.  That doesn't mean that it is not the external command's fault.  The command line args or environment variables could be different, etc.  You need to check the stderr contents.